# Essential difference between using StreamBuilder and StreamProvider

Tags: flutter, dart, provider, stream-builder

Could please someone to explain what essential difference (cons/pros) between using of *StreamBuilder* widget and *StreamProvider* (provider package). Why and when I need to use *StreamProvider*?

P.S. Moreover why do I need so many other providers (like ListenableProvider, ChangeNotifierProvider etc)? What advantage they give except naming? I can use Provider constructor to create any kind of data to be provided, right?

Comment: The main difference is that you don't to care about the event with StreamProvider, StreamBuilder provider on the other hand require you check conditionally the state of the current Snapshot (ConnectionState.done, .waiting, hasError, hasData, etc)

Comment: @GaurisJavier, I not agree. Both StreamBuilder/StreamProvider has `builder` method with parameter `snapshopt` or `object` accordingly. And to avoid `null` crash in `StreamBuilder` you need to check if `snapshot.hasData` but in `StreamProvider` you need to check if `object != null`. So this is not a case.

Comment: The builder methods have different signature, if you notice the StreamProvider one, doesn't have the Snapshot parameter, instead has a error builder, transition builder. The StreamProvider doesn't tell which state stream is (ConnectionState.done, .waiting). I stated that with the StreamProvider you don't need care about the event, and that's true. You don't have the paramater Snapshot for it. And also you have the parameter updateShouldNotify for checking when you data is valid, no just if is null or not.

Comment: O, I ask from other side. When I can use StreamProvider? What the advantage of StreamProvider before StreamBuilder? How to define the moment when I need StreamBuilder or StreamProvider? In principle this was my question.

P.S. Moreover why do I need so many other providers (like ListenableProvider, ChangeNotifierProvider etc)? What advantage they give except naming? I can use Provider constructor to create any kind of data to be provided, right?

Comment: Exactly, you have access to the stream throught the Provider context ( Provider.of<int>), if you don't have a very deep widget tree there is not too much difference. But when you have very deep widget tree like this: StreamProvider<int> -> MyCustomParent -> AnotherChildWidget -> AnotherChildWidgetDeeper - ***Provider.of<int>(context)***. Othewise, with the StreamBuilder you'll need to pass the Snpashot data as construtor reference until de deepest child. Something difficult to mantain.

Answer (score 2):

Use `StreamBuilder` for a stream that you are sure you will only need at that same widget. Use `StreamProvider` if your app is growing, passing this stream data through your app widgets will get messy.

> `StreamProvider` is a more complete solution than `StreamBuilder`:
>
> - [`StreamBuilder`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StreamBuilder-class.html)
>   is a widget that comes with Flutter, and rebuilds itself every time
>   the stream gets updated.
> - [`StreamProvider`](https://pub.dev/documentation/provider/latest/provider/StreamProvider-class.html)
>   is a widget that comes with the [Provider
>   package](https://pub.dev/packages/provider), it was built using
>   `StreamBuilder`, but combines this with
>   [`InheritedWidget`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/InheritedWidget-class.html),
>   allowing you to pass information through the tree of widgets
>   efficiently.

You can also read through this article ["Making sense of all those Flutter Providers"](https://medium.com/flutter-community/making-sense-all-of-those-flutter-providers-e842e18f45dd) to understand what each of the main Provider types are for and watch [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=budqAnwn740) that explains an evolution from using using `StreamBuilder` to `StreamProvider` and their benefits.